# Is there an ida plugin that disassemble in visual c inline assembly (visual studio)?

Tags: ida, assembly

I have a question... Is there an ida plugin that disassemble the file in visual studio inline assembly? I found this https://github.com/binrapt/ida but when I load it in ida, it complains about "No module named nil.file"... Where can I find this "nil.file"? I searched in the web but I can't find anything ahah

Comment: your question is unclear... what specifically you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

this imho is not a plugin

it is python script

possibly to be used with idapython

it list nil as a module to be imported

so you may need to install it

just gave a search with pip

and i get

```
C:\>pip search nil
nil (0.2.0)  - CMGS cOde ToOls
```

so do

```
C:\>pip install nil
```